# Update column name for existing Entity class using Hibernate Annotation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have one column in my Entity Class like :

```
@Column(name = "createdBy", nullable = false)

private String createdBy;
```

Later i need to update column name.

Is there any way to update the column name using hibernate annotation which will not generate new column.

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking

Comment: I want to update the name of column using hibernate annotation.

Comment: Probably you could just rename column in your database and then change annotation value.

Comment: `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` should do the Job if my understanding is correct

Comment: @AnarSultanov any other way except like : ALTER TABLE "table_name"
Change "column 1" "column 2" ["Data Type"];

Comment: @Jens you are not correct. It will try to create additional column with new name, but will throw exception because of nullable=false

Comment: @Steklorez update is used for hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

Comment: @kret which annotation is used for it?

Comment: @Piyush other way is: ALTER TABLE `table` RENAME COLUMN `old_name` TO `new_name`;

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You should use annotation **and** SQL script to modify table.